# Ruby on Rails: heroku database push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku

When I try and run `heroku db:push` I get this error.

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/heroku: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku can't find Ruby.  This is common if you're using RVM or something to manage your Ruby installations.  How did you install Heroku, and how did you install Ruby?

Comment: I used this guide http://fatal-errors.com/ubuntu-10-ruby-1-9-rails-3-not-working-solved/99008

Comment: So you are using RVM.  Did you install Heroku using the Toolbelt d/l from their website, or did you 'gem install heroku'?  If you did the former, then removing and reinstalling it as a gem will probably be your quickest solution.